# Cross platform package json

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-modules, package.json

I want to create a cross platform package json which needs to work in both mac and windows.

I have a scripts object

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run cleanup && webpack --watch",
    "build": "npm run cleanup && NODE_ENV=\"production\" webpack",
    "lint": "eslint ./main/content/jcr_root/etc/designs/digital/clientlibs/src/js --fix -f table --ext .js --ext .jsx || true",
    "cleanup": "rm -rf ./main/content/jcr_root/etc/designs/digital/clientlibs/dist"
  },
```

I have tried everything but cannot set it as cross platform. Please help me with this.

Comment: You can't use `rm` on Windows unless it's assumed to be configured with MinGW. For `cleanup`, Check out [`rimraf`](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to rely on node modules to do the job.

For `rm -rf` there is a node package called `rimraf`.

Install the package via

```
$ npm i -D rimraf
```

And adjust your script to use it:

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rimraf ./main/..."
}
```

Since node packages are mostly cross-OS, this should work.

You might also want to take a look at `cross-env` to set your NODE_ENV.

Let me know, if any additional help is required. :-)

**Edit:**

Since you are using webpack, there are also plugins for clean tasks as well as linting. For further information please take a look at:

- [clean-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin)
- [eslint-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader)

Comment: @VahRun It would be kind of you, to flag the answer as accepted then :-)